# Figaro in IRB console without Rails?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, environment-variables

Environment:
Ubuntu 18.04
Ruby 2.5.1
Private gem

Steps followed:

- `gem 'figaro'` in the Gemfile
- `bundle install` => created config.yml
- uncommented the demo variables to test drive Figaro
- `require 'figaro'` in bin/console
- `bin/console` from the command line

I can't access the variables in figaro.  Is there a way to use figaro without using Rails?

**Demo Variables:**

```
# Add configuration values here, as shown below.
#
pusher_app_id: "2954"
pusher_key: 7381a978f7dd7f9a1117
pusher_secret: abdc3b896a0ffb85d373
stripe_api_key: sk_test_2J0l093xOyW72XUYJHE4Dv2r
stripe_publishable_key: pk_test_ro9jV5SNwGb1yYlQfzG17LHK

production:
  stripe_api_key: sk_live_EeHnL644i6zo4Iyq4v1KdV9H
  stripe_publishable_key: pk_live_9lcthxpSIHbGwmdO941O1XVU
```

Comment: *"Is there a way to use figaro without using Rails?"* version >= 1.0 is no longer rails dependent so the simple answer is "Yes". Please post your actual issue as I am assuming this is not your actual question but you have given us nothing to go on other than *"I can't access the variables in figaro"*

Answer (score 0):

You can access those demo variable like below in rails console

```
ENV['pusher_app_id'] #=> '2954'
ENV['pusher_key'] #=>  '7381a978f7dd7f9a1117'
```

By using **Figaro.env** you can access by:

```
Figaro.env.pusher_app_id #=> '2954'
Figaro.env.pusher_key #=>  '7381a978f7dd7f9a1117'
```